# What does the extent / manySelect method in RxJS actually do?

Tags: rxjs

According to https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/manyselect.md, the `extent` / `manySelect` method is a comonadic transformer, which has the form of `Observable a -> (Observable a -> b) -> Observable b`, the "reversed" version of `selectMany` / `flatMat`.

The example given in the documentation:

```
var source = Rx.Observable.range(0, 3)
    .manySelect(function (ys) { return ys.first(); })
    .mergeAll();

var subscription = source.subscribe(
    function (x) {
        console.log('Next: ' + x);
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
    },
    function () {
        console.log('Completed');
    });

// => Next: 0
// => Next: 1
// => Next: 2
// => Completed
```

My understanding is that `manySelect` is wrapping each observed value into an `Observable` (by something like `Rx.Observable.just(x)`), then put it into the selector function, finally merge all returned values into a new `Observable`.

However, if I change `ys.first()` to `ys.count()` or `ys.last()`, the program crashes and says `Error: TypeError: innerSource.subscribe is not a function`.

What's happening? What does `manySelect` really do, and when should we use it?

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/dexutet/1/edit?html,js,console)

<del>Also a minor question:

When testing manySelect, I found that `Rx.Observable.range(0, 5).flatMap(() => [1, 2, 3, 4])` results in a sequence like below:

    onNext: 1
    onNext: 2
    onNext: 1
    onNext: 3
    onNext: 2
    onNext: 1
    onNext: 4
    onNext: 3
    onNext: 2
    onNext: 1
    onNext: 4
    onNext: 3
    onNext: 2
    onNext: 1
    onNext: 4
    onNext: 3
    onNext: 2
    onNext: 4
    onNext: 3
    onNext: 4
    Completed

While `Rx.Observable.interval(0).take(10).flatMap(() => [1, 2, 3, 4])` gives a result with the correct sequence.

Is this a bug or feature?</del>

Thanks @user3743222, I found the answer for the behavior of flatMap:

> Note that FlatMap merges the emissions of these Observables, so that they may interleave.

Answer (score 0):

Two extra ressources for understanding `manySelect`:

- [the unit tests](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/tests/observable/manyselect.js)!
- [the marbles](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html). This one should make it clear why your latest example behaves as it does. For your first question, you should provide a jsfiddle so it can be reproduced.
- [the actual implementation](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/src/core/linq/observable/manyselect.js)

> The `manySelect` operator is often described as a “comonadic bind.” If that clears things up for you, you’re welcome. Elsewise,
>   here’s an explanation:
>
> `manySelect` internally transforms each item emitted by the source
>   Observable into an Observable that emits that item and all items
>   subsequently emitted by the source Observable, in the same order. So,
>   for example, it internally transforms an Observable that emits the
>   numbers 1,2,3 into three Observables: one that emits 1,2,3, one that
>   emits 2,3, and one that emits 3.
>
> Then `manySelect` passes each of these Observables into a function
>   that you provide, and emits, as the emissions from the Observable that
>   `manySelect` returns, the return values from those function calls.
>
> In this way, each item emitted by the resulting Observable is a
>   function of the corresponding item in the source Observable and all of
>   the items emitted by the source Observable after it.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Now I know why the flatMap will act like that: "Note that FlatMap merges the emissions of these Observables, so that they may interleave. "

Comment: But I still don't understand why there will be errors when I use other operators like `last` or `count`...
https://jsfiddle.net/u5rs0yfg/
http://jsbin.com/dexutet/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: This has probably to do with the implementation of the `manySelect` : https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/src/core/linq/observable/manyselect.js. A chained pattern is used so that the emission of one value is emitted to several observables. What happens with `last` or `count` is that they do not emit till the source is completed (unlike `first`). So when the chaining occurs later, there is nothing to chain anymore (that's my hypothesis).

Comment: To confirm this, change `this` with any operator that does not wait for the stream completion, and replace `count` with any other operator with awaits termination of the stream (`toArray` for example). You will see the exact same behavior.

Comment: In any case, it does not really matter why, it matters that you can't change it. Usually you do not have to care about the side-effects happening in the implementation of the Rxjs operators as most of the time they do not affect you. You do not most of the time have to be care for example of the order in which subscription happens when you have multiple subscriptions, but sometimes you will have to. In any case, there is no more answer to your question than looking at the code.